# Updating the SelectedItem in an ItemsControl (ComboBox) in a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, combobox, dependency-properties

Before any item in a `ComboBox` is selected, its `SelectedItem`is null and the `ComboBox` itself is visually blank.  Once something is selected, there doesn't seem to be any way for the user to select "the absence of a selection" (though it can be done by setting `SelectedItem` to null in code).

My ComboBoxes are bound to ObservableCollections of my objects.  I don't want to add a "special" first null-like object to the front of every ObservableCollection.  So I'm taking this opportunity to learn a bit about writing a UserControl.

The problem is `SelectedItem` doesn't work the way it normally does.  That is, the `ComboBox` is nicely bound to a backing `ObservableCollection`, but picking something from the `ComboBox` doesn't update the `SelectedItem` it's supposed to be bound to.

I feel like I need to be passing along some information from the ComboBox in the UserControl to...somewhere.  Am I on the right track?  What should I be googling for?

C#:

```
public partial class ClearableComboBox : UserControl
{
    public ClearableComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)base.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource",
            typeof(IEnumerable),
            typeof(ClearableComboBox));

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)base.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(ClearableComboBox));

    public string DisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ClearableComboBox));

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.ClearableComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             x:Name="root">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Click="Button_Click" ToolTip="Clear">
            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/img/icons/silk/cross.png" Stretch="None" />
        </Button>
        <ComboBox
            Name="comboBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ItemsSource}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=SelectedItem}"
            DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DisplayMemberPath}" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Usage:

```
<wpfControl:ClearableComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Things}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="SomeProperty"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedThing}" />

// Picking a Thing doesn't update SelectedThing :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since combobox derives from `Selector` class which in turn derives from `ItemsControl`. So, by deriving from UserControl you are devoiding your combobox with properties of Selector class which might internally handle the Selection thing for you. so, i would suggest instead of deriving it from UserControl, you should derive it from Combobox like this -

```
public partial class ClearableComboBox : ComboBox
```

So, that ways you won't have to override the `ItemsSource`, DisplayMemberPath etc. in your class since it s already present in the `ComboBox` class. You can always extend your class further to provide addidtional features which is in your case setting the `SelectedItem` to null on some button click. Hope this is what you want..

**EDIT (Custom Control)**

Creating  a Custom Control is your answer here, to get started if you are not aware of it, look at this for start - http://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

When you create a Custom Control say CustomControl1, replace the template for CustomControl1 in your `Generic.xaml` file with this one -

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
              <DockPanel>
                 <Button Name="btn" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ToolTip="Clear" Width="20">
                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/img/icons/silk/cross.png" Stretch="None" />
                </Button>
                <ComboBox Name="comboBox"
                          ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                          SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}" />
              </DockPanel>
     </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

By default your `CustomControl1` class will be derived from `Control`. Replace it to derive from class `ComboBox` so that you don't have declare DP's yet over again like this and copy paste this code there -

```
public class CustomControl1 : ComboBox
{
        private Button clearButton;
        private ComboBox comboBox;

        static CustomControl1()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            clearButton = GetTemplateChild("btn") as Button;
            comboBox = GetTemplateChild("comboBox") as ComboBox;
            clearButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(clearButton_Click);
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox.SelectedItem = null;
        }
}
```

Now, your CustomControl1 class is ready for use in your other xaml files like this -

```
<local:CustomControl1 ItemsSource="{Binding YourSource}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem}"
                      Height="50" Width="200"/>
```

Comment: How would you suggest I clear my ClearableComboBox via mouseclick?

Comment: I have updated my answer with use of Custom Control. Have a look and let me know in case of any issues.

Comment: When I use `<local:CustomControl1 ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo, Mode=TwoWay}" />` it gets filled with Foos but SelectedFoo doesn't get updated when I choose a Foo from the dropdown.

Comment: Had to use the following:  `SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedItem}"`

Answer (score 0):

I chose to handle the key press event on the combo box and handle the escape key press to clear out the combo box's `SelectedItem`.

Comment: The combo box is in a Window which was shown with ShowDialog(), so the escape key will close the window instead of clearing the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better way, develop a wrapper/Adorner for `ComboBox`, that adds a button next to the `ComboBox` and wipe the selection on click.

Comment: Yes, which didn't help.  I believe IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem has more to do with the underlying CollectionView (or CollectionViewSource?).